# Is it possible to render part of the screen in different pixel density using openGL?

Tags: opengl, resolution, pixel

Say I have an openGL screen and I want to render part of the screen in different pixel density than the whole screen pixel density. Is it possible and if possible how?

Comment: "*different pixel density*" What does that mean?

Comment: @NicolBolas say you have a screen rendered with 640*480 resolution, so the pixels per inch (pixel density) will be same across the screen, now I want to vary this pixel density of the scene in different part of the screen.

Say I have a scene having different objects. Now I want to render some of the objects with more resolution than the other. I was thinking of the possibility of this optimization, but I'm not sure if it can be done with any existing 3D API's like openGL.

Comment: I doubt you can do that. You can cheat the looks of it by rendering to different frame buffers depending on the resolution you want and then putting the image together, but that's not an optimization. What you want is Level of Detail. Models with reduced polygon counts, mip-mapping, etc.

Comment: is http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/dynamic-resolution-rendering-article what you were thinking of doing?

Comment: @Adam I had a look at this before asking here. The concept is somewhat similar, but what I wanted to do is vary the resolution of part of the scene instead of changing the whole scene resolution. I'm wondering if doing such stuff is possible with any existing 3D API's (openGL/directX) out there.

Comment: The result might look like a strongly compressed JPEG image.

Comment: @Masum: To what end? Your screen, where you're eventually going to show these images, has a single resolution. What's the point of giving one area a higher resolution than the actual display device? Unless you're talking about antialiasing, which is a completely different subject.

Comment: I suspect any variation of resolution across the 3D scene would tend to look like a depth of field effect. The only other thing I've seen done at a lower resolution is particles because they tend to be fill bound and are often blurry anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Figure out which portions of the screen you want to render at what resolutions, and render them into FBOs of appropriate sizes.

Once you have your different elements rendered into separate FBOs, you can then composite them together into the main framebuffer using [glBlitFramebuffer()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml).

Or alternately, if you don't want to composite them together as complete rectangles (which is what glBlitFramebuffer() will do), then you can bind the various FBOs as textures, and draw from them to the main framebuffer with triangles, in whatever manner suits your desired effect.